# How to count the lines of a <pre> poem using css?

Tags: css, html

I want to display Beowulf on my webpage, the full poem. My code so far:

```
<head>
<title>Beowulf</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    body {padding: 10% 25%;}
    pre {font-family: "Times New Roman";  font-size: 100%;} 

</style>
</head> 

<body>
<h3>Beowulf</h3><br>

<pre>Now Beowulf bode in the burg of the Scyldings,
leader beloved, and long he ruled
in fame with all folk, since his father had gone
(...)
of furious flame. Nor far was that day
when father and son-in-law stood in feud
for warfare and hatred that woke again. (...)</pre>
</body>
```

Now how to get every fifth line numbered? I would like to position the numbers on the extreme edge of the right side.

I would appretiate if you tried to explain this issue to me as didatically as possible. I am a friend of simplicity and I would give preference to codes that shouldn't be bigger than the Beowulf poem itself (if you get the message!), so preferably css.

If javascrpit is the only way to get there, I would kindly ask you to formulate your answer in the most didactical way you can. My programming skills are "lower-intermediate" and unfortunately I didn't find any concrete information on the web, not even at w3schools. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: You'd have to wrap each line in its own element (and use `:nth-child()` syntax), whether you use JavaScript (or one of its libraries) to do this, or do it manually when writing the page is irrelevant; but CSS – sadly – has no `:nth-line()` selector.

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping each line in its own element and which element would that be?

Comment: Related: http://codepen.io/elomatreb/pen/hbgxp . For future googling reference, more people seem to be concerned with numbering lines of code than lines of poems. :)

Answer (score 2):

CSS styles elements or pseudo-elements, not text lines. So you need to modify your HTML or use JS.

For example, you can get the text, split it into lines, and wrap each one inside a list item of an ordered list.

The, you can use a CSS counter to associate each line with its number, `:nth-child` to select each 5n-th line, and a pseudo-element to insert the counter. To align the numbers properly, you can use CSS tables.

```js
var old = document.getElementById('poem'),
    poem = document.createElement('ol');
poem.id = 'poem';
old.textContent.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = line;
  poem.appendChild(li);
});
old.parentNode.replaceChild(poem, old);
```

```css
body {padding: 10% 25%;}
#poem {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: line;
}
#poem > li {
  display: table-row;
  white-space: pre;
  counter-increment: line;
}
#poem > li:nth-child(5n+1):after {
  content: counter(line);
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<h3>Beowulf</h3><br>
<pre id="poem">Now Beowulf bode in the burg of the Scyldings,
leader beloved, and long he ruled
in fame with all folk, since his father had gone
away from the world, till awoke an heir,
haughty Healfdene, who held through life,
sage and sturdy, the Scyldings glad.
Then, one after one, there woke to him,
to the chieftain of clansmen, children four:
Heorogar, then Hrothgar, then Halga brave;
and I heard that -- was -- 's queen,
the Heathoscylfing's helpmate dear.
To Hrothgar was given such glory of war,
such honor of combat, that all his kin
obeyed him gladly till great grew his band
of youthful comrades. It came in his mind
to bid his henchmen a hall uprear,
ia master mead-house, mightier far
than ever was seen by the sons of earth,
and within it, then, to old and young
he would all allot that the Lord had sent him,
save only the land and the lives of his men.
Wide, I heard, was the work commanded,
for many a tribe this mid-earth round,
to fashion the folkstead. It fell, as he ordered,
in rapid achievement that ready it stood there,
of halls the noblest: Heorot he named it
whose message had might in many a land.
Not reckless of promise, the rings he dealt,
treasure at banquet: there towered the hall,
high, gabled wide, the hot surge waiting
of furious flame. Nor far was that day
when father and son-in-law stood in feud
for warfare and hatred that woke again. (...)</pre>
```

Comment: What you did was to divide the poem into section like the other guy. I need no sections, but actual line counting, like 5, 10, 15 etc. It would be great if the counters were on a vertical line, on the right side and a bit far from the poem in order not to get in the way of the readers. Is it possible to do this with JS?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?    http://jsfiddle.net/g1xh9tjj/7/

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var text = $('pre').text(),
        textLines = text.split(/\n/g),
        index = 1,
        occurance = 5,
        paragraphNumber = occurance,
        output = '<div>1</div>';

    textLines.forEach(function(entry, arrayIndex) {
        if (arrayIndex > 0) {
            output += '<br />';
        }

        if (index === occurance) {
            output += '<div>'+paragraphNumber+'</div>'+entry;
            index = 1;
            paragraphNumber += occurance;
            return;
        } else {
            output += entry;
        }
        index++;
    });

    $('pre').html(output);
});
```

CSS:

```
pre {
    width: 400px;
}

pre div {
    float: right;
}
```

Result will be:

```
1Now Beowulf bode in the burg of the Scyldings,
leader beloved, and long he ruled
in fame with all folk, since his father had gone
away from the world, till awoke an heir,
5haughty Healfdene, who held through life,
sage and sturdy, the Scyldings glad.
Then, one after one, there woke to him,
to the chieftain of clansmen, children four:
Heorogar, then Hrothgar, then Halga brave;
10and I heard that -- was -- 's queen,
the Heathoscylfing's helpmate dear.
To Hrothgar was given such glory of war,
such honor of combat, that all his kin
obeyed him gladly till great grew his band
15of youthful comrades. It came in his mind
to bid his henchmen a hall uprear,
ia master mead-house, mightier far
than ever was seen by the sons of earth,
and within it, then, to old and young
20he would all allot that the Lord had sent him,
save only the land and the lives of his men.
Wide, I heard, was the work commanded,
for many a tribe this mid-earth round,
to fashion the folkstead. It fell, as he ordered,
25in rapid achievement that ready it stood there,
of halls the noblest: Heorot he named it
whose message had might in many a land.
Not reckless of promise, the rings he dealt,
treasure at banquet: there towered the hall,
30high, gabled wide, the hot surge waiting
of furious flame. Nor far was that day
when father and son-in-law stood in feud
for warfare and hatred that woke again. (...)
```

Comment: Thank you! You are dividing the poem into sections, like 1., 2., 3., 4., but what I need is the lines to be counted, like 5, 10, 15, 20, just like line numbers. You placed the counters in front of the lines. Is it possible to place them behing the lines in a vertical line close to the right edge?

Comment: I've updated my answer (check the example on jsfiddle to see numbers on the right hand side).

Comment: oh yes, that looks much better! but it still adds a line break, so people will think there is a new stanza. it would be better if the number could stand on the same line it refers to, and whitout any break. Is that possible? :-)

Comment: Updated jsfiddle, now the numbers should be on the same line as poem lines.

Comment: Brilliant, that is very helpful! Is it possible to get rid of the dot after the number? Not that this is a big issue, just asking...

Comment: by the way, my html file is not recognising this language. Do I need to write <script> before and after it? Is there a safe place to place this code? I've placed in both on body and then on head but my file is not reading it. :(

Comment: Dot have been removed, check fiddle again. Here is a full working HTML page: http://fiddle.jshell.net/g1xh9tjj/7/show/

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been very helpful!! On the source of this html, I can see <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script> . Is this an external sheet somewhere? You are using jquery. Where can I get more information about that language? It's not working on my html file, it looks as if I am making some basic mistake...

Comment: You can just re-use that script on your site, it's a CDN. jQuery is a JS library which support different browsers and provides with ready to use helper functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know how to add lines to a poem in the right way :-)

Comment: If it's sorted, then can you mark my answer as a Correct Answer? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to mark answers so far, sorry. But the answer was very good indeed!

Comment: Some more questions if you are there: 1) Is it possible to get rid of the first number in the poem? By convention, it should start with the number 5 in the fifth line. 2) Is it possible to tell jquery that it should not read empty lines? Some poems have a break after 50 or 100 lines and this should not be counted. Sometimes there is a title between breaks, but it should not be counted as well. 3) In the worst case, like in verse plays, a single line is divided into 2 or 3 smaller lines which should be counted as one, e.g. Macbeth, 1st scene, line 6. Could jquery be taught to recognise that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean CSS solution, just approximate and a bit awkward hack for finite length text.  Itʼs flaw is clearly visible: no automatic counter, just positioned generated content with static text:

```css
    body {padding: 10% 25%;}
    pre {font-family: "Times New Roman";  font-size: 100%;} 

div {
 margin-left: -2em;
 padding-left: 2em; /* …create space for numbers */
 overflow: hidden; /* …and prevent them from leaking */
}
pre {
 position: relative;
}
pre:before {
 content: '\a\a\a\a 5\a\a\a\a 10\a\a\a\a 15\a\a\a\a 20'; /* and so on */
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: -2em;
 width: 2em;
 text-align: right;
 color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div>
<pre>Now Beowulf bode in the burg of the Scyldings,
leader beloved, and long he ruled
in fame with all folk, since his father had gone
away from the world, till awoke an heir,
haughty Healfdene, who held through life,
sage and sturdy, the Scyldings glad.
Then, one after one, there woke to him,
to the chieftain of clansmen, children four:
Heorogar, then Hrothgar, then Halga brave;
and I heard that -- was -- 's queen,
the Heathoscylfing's helpmate dear.
To Hrothgar was given such glory of war,
such honor of combat, that all his kin
obeyed him gladly till great grew his band
of youthful comrades. It came in his mind (…)</pre></div>
```

I have put numbers left, because I overlooked sentence about "extreme edge of the right side" first.

Comment: Oh yes, I see, it's too complicated and would not work with an epic poem with more than 3000 lines... Which would be the JS alternative then? Anything easy?